# way to open and load a file in memory

Tags: c, linux, file-io

Is there a way such that I can open and load a file directly in memory?
I have lot of legacy code that opens a file present on network, and then does
seeks and reads from this file. I want to avoid the reads and seeks over the network.
Hence, if I could load the file in memory, when I open it, I could have efficient seeks.
Any ideas?
I'm working wtih C on Linux.

Comment: mmpa would return a pointer to the memory location where the file is loaded. My legacy code works on the file pointer. I would then need to change lot of code for this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`mmap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) function, or plain `open` and `read` it all into a buffer you've allocated with `malloc`.

But please do benchmark. You might get very little (or none at all) improvement from this "manual buffering". The OS already does caching for you.

Comment: the mmap link is somewhat broken

Answer (score 2):

As Mat said, have a look at the mmap function. (It's probably the easier way)
http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap

If you prefer malloc, this link should help you:
http://www.anyexample.com/programming/c/how_to_load_file_into_memory_using_plain_ansi_c_language.xml